# How to Trigger in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

**I want to create a Trigger in MySql I did it with SQL Server at school in my class, but for my project, my web hoster only give me MySql DataBase and if I want a SQL Server DB I need to buy a VPS and I can't afford it so i'll do with MySql, I read about MySql Trigger and I saw that they are really more hard to do than SQL Server Trigger.**

**First here is every article I read about trigger in MySql (To be sure to not be placed as a duplica):**

```
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx/
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745441/how-to-write-trigger-with-multiple-condition-in-mysql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775826/how-to-declare-variables-in-trigger-with-mysql
```

**And here is the SQL Server code I made:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER file_verified_if_admin ON tblOpenSource
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @source_id          INT;
    DECLARE @verified           TEXT;
    DECLARE @client_id          INT;

    DECLARE c_info CURSOR FOR
        SELECT source_id, verified, client_id FROM inserted;
    OPEN c_info;

    FETCH c_info INTO @source_id,@verified,@client_id;
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    BEGIN
        
        IF ((SELECT tblClients.grade FROM tblClients JOIN tblOpenSource ON tblOpenSource.client_id = tblClients.client_id;) == 'admin')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tblOpenSource SET verified = 'verified' WHERE source_id = @source_id;
        END;
    END;
    CLOSE c_info;
    DEALLOCATE c_info;
END;
```

**Here is what I made with MySql and I still have errors, can someone help me ?**

```
CREATE TRIGGER file_verified_if_admin 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE ON tblOpenSource 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE client_grade text;
    SET @client_grade = (SELECT tblClients.grade FROM tblClients JOIN tblOpenSource ON tblClients.client_id = tblOpenSource.client_id);
    IF (@client_grade = 'admin')
    UPDATE tblOpenSource SET verified = 'verified' WHERE source_id = NEW.source_id;
END;
```

**It says I have an error near my DELCARE, but I don't understand why, because I heard we don't need an "@" in the declaration.**

**What it is supposed to do, is to look if the file as been publied by an admin and if yes, it should update the verified column and change the text for verified**

Comment: *I read about MySql Trigger and I saw that they are really more hard to do than SQL Server Trigger.* No. Triggers in these DBMSs are different simply. *`AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`* Read User Manual one more time - there is NO multi-actional triggers in MySQL. *`ON tblOpenSource ... UPDATE tblOpenSource`* - You cannot affect the table which' change fires the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql desn_'t allow multiple trigger in one goal you have to define then all.

Maysql needs `DELIMITER`to know where the trigger starts and ends

Last the IÌF CLause`is in  mysql different.

This is the correct syntax, you can change it further by using `SELECT INTO`

UPDATE @Akina poited out,

that your query will not run, you **can't change** a row that  has triggert the Trigger, mysql will not not allow that, so for your insert trigger, has to be change accordingly.
For the UPDATE Trigger goes teh saem.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER file_verified_if_admin 
BEFORE INSERT ON tblOpenSource 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET @client_grade = (SELECT tblClients.grade FROM tblClients JOIN tblOpenSource ON tblClients.client_id = tblOpenSource.client_id);
    IF (@client_grade = 'admin') then
        SET NEW.verified = 'verified';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `ON tblOpenSource ... UPDATE tblOpenSource`

Comment: client_grade and @client_grade variables are not the same!

Comment: So if I correctly understand DELIMITER is doing a lil bit as begin but we need to put it at the beginning of the trigger to advert that it is starting and it is ending. And NEW is the same as the table inserted in SQL Server ?

Comment: Yes DELIMITERtells mysql when a trigger starts and ends, it is need when you have mire than one sql comand. the NEW is the row tha will be inserted and with the `BEFORE IÄNSERT` you can change the values of that riw before it gets inseted and teh same gies for BEFORE UPDATE

Comment: I tried, but I don't have enough reputation, my last question made me lose a lot of rep :(

Comment: But how could I do it if I wanted to do it wither the AFTER INSERT ? Just to know because I would need to update the verified where the file_id = current file_id

Comment: Write a UPDATE TRIGGER and  it runs when you update, but what shpuld change after the insert is done nothing. And you have to adept your code to the peculiarity of the databse. Also you can always accept the answer, independent of rep